# Is there a way to make a @Scheduled function run on initialisation?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, scheduled-tasks

I want my program to download from an API every day at 5 AM and at launch. Is there a way to achieve this?

```
  @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 5 * * *", zone = "Europe/Oslo")
  fun scheduledDL(link: String) {
      val xmlString = downloader.download(link)
    }
```

Comment: add @PostConstruct annotation

Comment: Don't use `@PostConstruct` for that. As you are using Spring Boot register an `ApplicationRunLIstener` which simply calls this method. That will be invoked after the application is up and running. `@PostConstruct` is called during application initializing and might be that not everything is up and running just yet.